# Enum String Name from Value

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum construct like this:

```
public enum EnumDisplayStatus
{
    None    = 1,
    Visible = 2,
    Hidden  = 3,
    MarkedForDeletion = 4
}
```

In my database, the enumerations are referenced by value. My question is, how can I turn the number representation of the enum back to the string name.

For example, given `2` the result should be `Visible`.

Answer (score 747, accepted):

You can convert the `int` back to an enumeration member with a simple cast, and then call `ToString()`:

```
int value = GetValueFromDb();
var enumDisplayStatus = (EnumDisplayStatus)value;
string stringValue = enumDisplayStatus.ToString();
```

Comment: Update: only certain overloads using IFormatProvider are deprecated. ToString() is fine. See http://groups.google.com/group/DotNetDevelopment/browse_thread/thread/dcdbeae086360208

Comment: What is the behavior in case of `enum Foo { A = 1, B= 1 }`?

Comment: @dbkk the documentation states that with regards to enums "your code should not make any assumptions about which string will be returned." because of the precise situation you quote. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx

Comment: An uptodated solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: shorter: var stringValue = ((EnumDisplayStatus)value).ToString()

Answer (score 264):

If you need to get a string `"Visible"` without getting `EnumDisplayStatus` instance you can do this:

```
int dbValue = GetDBValue();
string stringValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumDisplayStatus), dbValue);
```

Comment: If you about Mandoleen's answer there is an inaccuracy: Enum.GetName returns a string, not an Enum

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 207):

Try this:

```
string m = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnumClass), value);
```

Answer (score 96):

Use this:

```
string bob = nameof(EnumDisplayStatus.Visible);
```

Comment: C# 6+ required though.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you want to pass in a variable

Answer (score 51):

The fastest, compile time solution using `nameof` [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof).

Returns the literal type casing of the enum or in other cases, a `class`, `struct`, or *any kind* of `variable` (arg, param, local, etc).

```
public enum MyEnum {
    CSV,
    Excel
}


string enumAsString = nameof(MyEnum.CSV)
// enumAsString = "CSV"
```

**Note:**

- You wouldn't want to name an enum in full uppercase, but used to demonstrate the case-sensitivity of `nameof`.

Answer (score 30):

you can just cast it

```
int dbValue = 2;
EnumDisplayStatus enumValue = (EnumDisplayStatus)dbValue;
string stringName = enumValue.ToString(); //Visible
```

ah.. kent beat me to it :)

Answer (score 20):

**SOLUTION:**

```
int enumValue = 2; // The value for which you want to get string 
string enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumDisplayStatus), enumValue);
```

Also, using **GetName** is better than **Explicit casting of Enum**.

**[Code for Performance Benchmark]**

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch (); sw.Start (); sw.Stop (); sw.Reset ();
double sum = 0;
int n = 1000;
Console.WriteLine ("\nGetName method way:");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   sw.Start ();
   string t = Enum.GetName (typeof (Roles), roleValue);
   sw.Stop ();
   sum += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
   sw.Reset ();
}
Console.WriteLine ($"Average of {n} runs using Getname method casting way: {sum / n}");
Console.WriteLine ("\nExplicit casting way:");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   sw.Start ();
   string t = ((Roles)roleValue).ToString ();
   sw.Stop ();
   sum += sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
   sw.Reset ();
}
Console.WriteLine ($"Average of {n} runs using Explicit casting way: {sum / n}");
```

**[Sample result]**

```
GetName method way:
Average of 1000 runs using Getname method casting way: 0.000186899999999998
Explicit casting way:
Average of 1000 runs using Explicit casting way: 0.000627900000000002
```

Comment: This is a copy of a 7 year old answer. Can you explain why your's is better than the original?

Comment: @nvoigt Because, if I am correct, the ToString() API on Enum is now obsolete. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=netframework-4.8]

Comment: So... at least two other answers already provide the code you posted. What does your's provide over the one from Mandoleen or algreat?

Comment: @nvoigt They did not mention about its performance compared to Explicit casting. Is this sufficient for you to like my answer? :p Thanks anyway, I hope it will help someone. :)

Comment: We seem to have a communication problem. Are you on a mobile device or maybe did you not scroll down far enough? There are two exact copies of your answer from 7 years back. I named the answerers, so they should be easy to find. What does your answer provide that has not been here for at least 7 years already?

Answer (score 15):

DB to C#

```
EnumDisplayStatus status = (EnumDisplayStatus)int.Parse(GetValueFromDb());
```

C# to DB

```
string dbStatus = ((int)status).ToString();
```

Answer (score 15):

Given:

```
enum Colors {
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 3
};
```

In .NET 4.7 the following

```
Console.WriteLine( Enum.GetName( typeof(Colors), Colors.Green ) );
Console.WriteLine( Enum.GetName( typeof(Colors), 3 ) );
```

will display

```
Green
Blue
```

In .NET 6 the above still works, but also:

```
Console.WriteLine( Enum.GetName( Colors.Green ) );
Console.WriteLine( Enum.GetName( (Colors)3 ) );
```

will display:

```
Green
Blue
```

Answer (score 8):

Just need:

```
string stringName = EnumDisplayStatus.Visible.ToString("f");
// stringName == "Visible"
```

Comment: in most cases, this is pretty much identical to the top answer from 10 years ago; the addition of the `"f"` specifier is nuanced, and may or may not be what the caller wants (it depends on: what they want): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the date ahah. I think it is good to update a bit the old solution like this one. I won't be the last one to open this page. And thanks for your precision! :)

Answer (score 6):

i have used this code given below

```
 CustomerType = ((EnumCustomerType)(cus.CustomerType)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 5):

For getting the String value [Name]:

```
EnumDisplayStatus enumDisplayStatus = (EnumDisplayStatus)GetDBValue();
string stringValue = $"{enumDisplayStatus:G}";
```

And for getting the enum value:

```
string stringValue = $"{enumDisplayStatus:D}";
SetDBValue(Convert.ToInt32(stringValue ));
```

Comment: Why not just .ToString()? 'facepalm'

Answer (score 4):

Just cast the int to the enumeration type:

```
EnumDisplayStatus status = (EnumDisplayStatus) statusFromDatabase;
string statusString = status.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
string stringValue=( (MyEnum)(MyEnum.CSV)).ToString();
```

Comment: The cast is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Another option (inspired by [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum)) is to use the [`Type.GetEnumName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getenumname) method:

```
int enumValue = 2;
string enumName = typeof(EnumDisplayStatus).GetEnumName(enumValue);
```

Testing indicates it to be marginally faster than the `Enum.GetName()` method (about 4% over 1e8 iterations).