# Return string value in Enum

Tags: c#

I am trying to return the parameter names from the following enum model. Here is  my code

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


namespace Digital.HrAssist.Services.Models
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum EExitStatusDescription
    {
        Started,
        Incomplete,
        Completed,
        Cancelled,
        SubmittedForProcessing
    }
}


return o => new EmployeeExitItem
{
      ExitId = o.ExitId,
      EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId,
      KickoffDate = o.KickoffDate,
      Action = (EExitActions)o.ActionId,
      Status = (EExitStatus)o.StatusId,
      StatusDescription = (EExitStatusDescription)o.StatusDescription
};

public class EmployeeExitItem
{
    public Guid ExitId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime KickoffDate { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(EExitActions))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public EExitActions Action { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(EExitStatus))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public EExitStatus Status { get; set; }

    public EExitStatusDescription StatusDescription { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to get the parameter names like "Started", "Incomplete" etc however I am currently getting this error `"Cannot convert type 'string to 'digital.hrassist.services.models.EExitStatusDescription''"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731727/5228202 ?

Comment: Try StatusDescription = Enum.Parse(typeof(EExitStatusDescription), o.StatusDescription))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: StatusDescription is String?

Comment: @auburg I get a sysntax error `Syntax error, ',' expected`

Comment: could you please provide the `EmployeeExitItem`-class as well? It´s not clear if you want to convert an enum-value to string or a string-value to enum. Due to the error I suppose the latter. But your question states you want to return enum-names, which makes me suppose enum to string.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've added the class in the question

Answer (score 0):

Just :

```
EExitStatusDescription exit = EExitStatusDescription.Incomplete;

String value = exit.ToString();
```