# How Get enum attributes with values in c#?

Tags: c#

```
enum EmpName
{ 
    FirstName = 1, 
    LastName = 2
};
```

How do I get the following result:

1. `FirstName`
2. `LastName`

Comment: You definetely need [Enum.GetNames()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enum String Name from Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(EmpName)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Output will be:

> FirstName
>   LastName