# Converting Hex Color Code to Color Name (string)

Tags: c#

I want to convert a hex color code to the suitable string color name... with the following code I was able to get the hex code of the "most used" color in a photo:

```
class ColorMath
{
    public static string getDominantColor(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        //Used for tally
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;

        int total = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                r += clr.R;
                g += clr.G;
                b += clr.B;

                total++;
            }
        }

        //Calculate average
        r /= total;
        g /= total;
        b /= total;

        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        string hex = myColor.R.ToString("X2") + myColor.G.ToString("X2") + myColor.B.ToString("X2");

        return hex;
    }
}
```

So I want for a hex code like: #3A322B to appear something like "dark brown"

Comment: How do you plan on doing this for every possible colour combination?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net
try this. and your question is not clear. can you explain clearly?

Comment: I want to add some codes and refer them to a single color like if he sees something like  #ff0000 or anything similar to instantly show "Red".

Comment: You could match the hex code against the code for the predefined colours, but it won't work if your calculated value isn't one of those.

Comment: What do you expect to get for one of colors which is not a part of [Colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx) ? Otherwise a simple enumerating and check versus RGB values shouldn't be hard... Note, this is for WPF.

Comment: "unknown color" and I would like to let the user add the "Unknown Color" and say the name of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert hex code to color name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791710/convert-hex-code-to-color-name) (that's for winforms).

Comment: Just add `return "dark brown";` ;-) No, seriously, on a color photograph blending all colors like your algorithm does, always will result in something like brown – the "average" color is something different than the dominant color; you probably want an algorithm like this one: https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief which quantizes colors using a median cut algorithm. See a demo here: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief

Comment: yeah That's true but I want it in c#

Comment: I find the suitable form in c# but looks so complicated and I don't know if it's free to use?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the colour is in the [`KnownColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) enum you can use [`ToKnownColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toknowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
KnownColor knownColor = color.ToKnownColor();
```

To note is the following from the MSDN docs:

> When the ToKnownColor method is applied to a Color structure that is created by using the FromArgb method, ToKnownColor returns 0, even if the ARGB value matches the ARGB value of a predefined color.

So to get your colour you could use something like the following from the hex code:

```
Color color = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(htmlString);
```

Where `htmlString` is in the form `#RRGGBB`.

To convert `KnownColor` to a string simply use `ToString` on the enum ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value)):

```
string name = knownColor.ToString();
```

Putting all of that together you can use this method:

```
string GetColourName(string htmlString)
{
    Color color = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(htmlString);
    KnownColor knownColor = color.ToKnownColor();

    string name = knownColor.ToString();
    return name.Equals("0") ? "Unknown" : name;
}
```

Calling it like:

```
string name = GetColourName("#00FF00");
```

Results in `Lime`.

I have also found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792104/4631427) to a similar question that seems to work quite well too which uses reflection and falls back to html colour names:

> ```
> string GetColorName(Color color)
> {
>     var colorProperties = typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
>                                        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Color));
>     foreach (var colorProperty in colorProperties) 
>     {
>         var colorPropertyValue = (Color)colorProperty.GetValue(null, null);
>         if (colorPropertyValue.R == color.R  && colorPropertyValue.G == color.G 
>          && colorPropertyValue.B == color.B)
>         {
>             return colorPropertyValue.Name;
>         }
>     }
>
>     //If unknown color, fallback to the hex value
>     //(or you could return null, "Unkown" or whatever you want)
>     return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
> }
> ```

Comment: Yeah it works now but there are so many unknown colors like:
(All the following didn't work)
#171B16
#9F806D
#584A45
#070603
And in the real life they look kind of obvious

Comment: @C.Cretan I advise you to read the MSDN docs I linked to about the `KnownColor` enum it tells you all the values it has. However the first example you linked to doesn't have a name even when I google it so I don't know what you expect to happen there

Comment: @C.Cretan Regarding the edit to your comment, just because they look like a colour does not mean they are that colour. For example `#EF0000` looks almost the same as Red (`#FF0000`) but it isn't.

Comment: @C.Cretan If my answer helped you find an answer to the main question, could you mark it as accepted so that others can find an answer to the question easier?

Comment: Is there also a version of this that gets the HUE name instead of the color name?