# how to get string value from Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am confused with Enum. This is my enum

```
enum Status
{
   Success = 1,
   Error = 0
}


public void CreateStatus(int enumId , string userName)
{
     Customer t = new Customer();
     t.Name = userName;
    // t.Status = (Status)status.ToString(); - throws build error
     t.Status = //here I am trying if I pass 1 Status ="Success", if I pass 0 Status = "Error"

}
```

> Error - Cannot convert string to enum.Status

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public string Status {get; set;}
}
```

How do I set the Status properties of the customer objecj using the Enum Status.?

(No If-Else or switch ladder)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to call `.ToString`

```
 t.Status = Status.Success.ToString();
```

[ToString() on Enum from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you have enum Id passed, you can run:

```
t.Status = ((Status)enumId).ToString();
```

It casts integer to Enum value and then call `ToString()`

**EDIT (better way):**
You can even change your method to:

```
public void CreateStatus(Status status , string userName)
```

and call it:

```
CreateStatus(1,"whatever");
```

and cast to string:

```
t.Status = status.ToString();
```

Comment: I am passing (int)enumId It can be 0 or 1. How can I map in this way

Comment: @Kgn-web check my edited answer, you need to cast int to enum

Answer (score 2):

Its easy you can use ToString() method to get the string value of an enum.

```
enum Status
{
   Success = 1,
   Error = 0
}

string foo = Status.Success.ToString();
```

Update

Its easier if you include the type of Enum within your method's inputs like below:

```
public void CreateStatus(Status enums, string userName)
{
     Customer t = new Customer();
     t.Name = userName;
     t.Status = enums.Success.ToString();

}
```