# How to map between int and property c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

In the project I'm working on, (.net Core) we are using a range slider ([noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/))to represent quality in a product filter.

[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHFzQ.png)

The slider returns an array of numbers as an example **[2, 4]** would be returned if the slider was set to **Good** and **Excellent** and I would need to retrieve all the products that match Good, Very Good, and Excellent in quality.

Here in lies some of the unique problems with this.
The products are pulled from a third party service, and I only receive the quality as the string value. So I need a way to assign a number value to the string value I receive so I can check for all products that have a quality >= to qualityArray[0] and <= to qualityArray[1]

What would be the best way to map between string to int so I can do the >= and <= check with the quality range and at the same time map the int to a string so when displaying the list of products that match the range I only have to display the string value? (**Very Good**)

I was imagining using an Enum or a Dictionary but I'm not sure what the advantages of either would be.

Comment: what type of object are you using to store the returned products from the 3rd party service?  And do you need to do the >= or <= quality  or are other avenues open?

Comment: The object is a product class

public class Product{
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public string Website {get;set;}
    public string Quality {get;set;}
    ...
}

I would be open to other ideas alternatives to >= and <= for comparing quality, but the slider is required for this project.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate a rating in its own class:

```
public class Rating
{
    public int Value { get; }

    private readonly IDictionary<string, int> _asValue = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"One", 1},
        {"Two", 2},
        {"Three", 3},
        {"Four", 4},
        {"Five", 5},
    };

    public Rating(string rating)
    {
        Value = _asValue[rating];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _asValue.First(pair => pair.Value == Value).Key;
    }
}
```

To compare ratings you would just need to get the Value from each rating:

```
var r1 = new Rating("One");
var r2 = new Rating("Two");
var result = r1.Value > r2.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the string value to an enum using `Enum.Parse` and then parse the enum to a string when required using `Enum.ToString`

Then you can say 
`QualitiyValues.Low >= myObject.Quality <= QualityValues.Medium`.

[Enum String Name from Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your slider is a simple array you might try the follwing or something similar:

```
       // This will be what is returned by your slider
int[] ar = [2,4];
 Dictionary<int, string> test = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                {1,"OK" },
                {2,"Good"},
                {3,"Very Good"},
                {4,"Excellent"}

            };

            List<string> choosenquality = new List<string>();
            for(int x =ar[0];x<=ar[1];x++)
            {
                choosenquality.Add(test[x]);
            }
//The following will be all the products that meet good, very good, and excellent
            IEnumerable<Productclass> tested = from x in myapps join y in choosenquality where x.Quality== y select x;
```