# Check is the input in Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I dont know why this so hard no..

I have to check is the user input in Enum.

Now i have two different methods, which tell (False or True) is input in the Enum. I do not want show those things to user, i just want program to print like:

"Your input "user input here" found in Car makers list with name "Audi"

```
using static System.Console;

namespace EnumAutomerkit
{
    enum Automerkit
    {
        Audi = 100,
        BMW = 101,
        Citroen = 102,
        Mercedes_Benz = 103,
        Skoda = 104,
        Toyota = 105,
        Volkswagen = 106,
        Volvo = 107
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("AUTOMERKIT");

            foreach (int luku in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Automerkit)))
                WriteLine($"{luku} = {Enum.GetName(typeof(Automerkit), luku)}");

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Valitse automerkki joko numerolla tai nimellä (tyhjä lopettaa): ");  //"Choose car maker with number or name (empty breaks): "
                string userinput = Console.ReadLine();

                int.TryParse(userinput, out int userinput2);//muuttaa annetun stringin int olioksi

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", userinput2, Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Automerkit), userinput2)); //this can check is the number user gave in enum
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", userinput, Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Automerkit), userinput)); //this can check is the text or chars user gave in enum


                if (userinput == "")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Enum.GetName(typeof(Automerkit), luku)` to get the name for an enum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GetName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=netframework-4.8) method to get the name of the enum value associated with its underlying value (there are other methods too, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309333/5133585)). You only need one `foreach` loop, and you can use string interpolation to print in the format `value = name`:

```
foreach (int rawValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Automerkit))) {
    WriteLine($"{rawValue} = {Enum.GetName(typeof(Automerkit), rawValue)}");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An enum value is automatically converted to an enum name when converted to string. Therefore you can write

```
foreach (Automerkit enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Automerkit))) {
    WriteLine($"{(int)enumValue} = {enumValue}");
}
```

Note that the foreach statement automatically converts the element type (`object` returned by `GetValues` here) to the type of the iteration variable (`Automerkit`).

For more information, see [The foreach statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement) section of the [C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement). The parameter of the `WriteLine` uses [String interpolation in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) (Microsoft Docs).

Comment: `GetValues` returns `System.Array` of the type passed into instead of object thereby not converting.

Comment: @snr, No. Try to use `foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Automerkit))) { ...` with a `var` and you will see that `enumValue` will be inferred as `object`. (Note that the code still works with `var`, so converting the object to the enum type is not required but better reflects the intent of the programmer). Note, even if the array is an `Automerkit[]`, it is returned as `System.Array`. Therefore you have to cast either the whole array or its elements if you want an object explicitly typed as `Automerkit`.

Comment: Sir, at first, thank your effort and nice explanation but `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Automerkit))` returns type of `Automerkit[]`. `enumValue` is of type `object`. Do you mean the type is cast to `Automerkit` type implicitly? (object -> Automerkit). Would you mind glancing at https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWJ39.png?

Comment: See the definition of [Enum.GetValues(Type) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8). It returns an [Array Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8) having an indexer [Array.IList.Item`[`Int32`]` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-item?view=netframework-4.8) returning an `object`. The runtime type of the items is `Automerkit`, but the static type at compile time is `object`. To see the real object you must cast it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Enum.GetNames` function and then parse the name to get the `int` value.

```
foreach (var merkkiluettelo in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Automerkit)))
{
    Enum.TryParse(merkkiluettelo, out Automerkit a);
    Console.WriteLine($"{(int)a} = {merkkiluettelo}");
}
```