# Is it possible to use Enum values rather than indexes in Javascript onChange function on a Select tag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got a select tag in my view that's populated with items from an enum in my class.  I'm using the selected value to show/hide elements on my page.  This was a set of radio buttons before but as the number of options grew, I wanted to put it in a nicer form control than a bunch of buttons.  To test functionality I'm just trying to display the selected value before I re-implement the show/hide.

My model

```
    [Serializable]
    public class AddUser
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Type")]
        public UserTypes UserType { get; set; }

        public enum UserTypes
        {
            [Display(Name = "Standard")]                    Standard,
            [Display(Name = "Standard + Email")]            StandardAndEmail,
            [Display(Name = "Standard + Email + Phone")]    StandardAndEmailAndPhone,
            [Display(Name = "Email Only")]                  EmailOnly,
            [Display(Name = "Phone Only")]                  PhoneOnly
        }
}
```

Tag from view View

```
<select id="userType" class="form-control" asp-for="UserType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<AddUser.UserTypes>()" onchange="userTypeSelect()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="UserType" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function userTypeSelect() {
        var userType = document.getElementById("userType").value;
        console.log('User Type: ' + userType)
    }
</script>
```

Here is the resulting HTML

[image: Raw HTML]

Desired result would be the rendered HTML options looking like this:

`<option value="Standard">Standard</option>`

Since I plan on using the value in Javascript, having access to the name rather than just an index would be ideal for code readability - especially since this isn't going to a database.  I've been at this all morning trying to figure out how to get this to work.

**Is this possible?  If so, is it still better to just use the ID anyway?**

Comment: It is possible, just more code. "Better" is a judgement call; only you can decide that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enum String Name from Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a X|Y question since on server side  you can get id from value or get value from id , so it's up to you to  pass id or value to server side from front end .  If you want to show `<option value="Standard">Standard</option>` you can write extension method like :

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumValueSelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
            .Select(x =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.ToString(),
                    Value = x.ToString()
                }), "Value", "Text");
    }

}
```

And use like :

```
<select id="userType" class="form-control" asp-for="UserType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumValueSelectList<aspnetcorerepos.Controllers.HomeController.AddUser.UserTypes>()" >
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

But IMO it's more clear to identify `0`/`1` rather than `Standard`/`StandardAndEmail` on server side . But it's your choice to use id/value and you can decide the logic .