# how to compare string list and enum list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enums

My User Class is given below

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public Roles Role { get; set; }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

My Role class is given below

```
public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
```

My enum is given below

```
public enum Roles
    {
        Admin,
        Guest,
        Accountant
    }
```

Getting error(Cannot compare string to enum) when compare string with enum values with the code given below

```
if(User.Roles.Where(m => _roles.Contains(m.RoleName)).ToList()))
    {

    }
```

=>* here m.RoleName getting error(Cannot compare string to enum)

Comment: type of _roles?

Comment: if you want to compare the Enum name, eg. "Admin" == Role.RoleName, will this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value

Comment: private readonly IList<Roles> _roles;

Comment: Roles is enum..

Answer (score 1):

You probably want one of these two variants:

```
User.Roles.Where(m => _roles.Any(r => r.ToString().Contains(m.RoleName)))
```

Or:

```
User.Roles.Where(m => _roles.Contains((Roles)Enum.Parse(typeof(Roles), m.RoleName)))
```

Comment: I prefer using generics for parsing `Enum.Parse<Roles>(m.RoleName)`

Comment: It is in the if condition

Comment: hai @Enigmativity, it is not working.  this is in if condition if(User.Roles.Where(m => _roles.Contains(m.RoleName)).ToList()))
    {

    }

Comment: @Noufal - You're saying that the code in your question doesn't work? We knew that already. Have you tried both of my suggestions? I did test both of those before posting.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev - The generic parse method for `Enum` is not available in 4.8 or earlier. It's definitely in 5.0.

Comment: Enigmativity, yes you are right, but I think .Net Core is mature enough to use it in answers, it is not so hard to figure out how to fallback to non-generic version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare like this:

```
        if (User.Roles.Any(r=> Enum.GetNames(typeof(Roles)).Contains(r.RoleName)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Successed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UnAuthrize");
        }
```